# Aiogram переодически выдает ошибку и тормозит работу бота. Как это можно решить?

Tags: python, aiogram

Переодически бот падает и через время вылезает такая ошибка:

```
Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443
```

Затем бот снова реагирует на все, но эта проблема повторяется.

Answer (score 0):

Данная ошибка обычно возникает при плохом соединение с интернетом, то есть, возможно, вы имеете плохой интернет, который иногда прерывается (пропадает). Вы можете решить эту проблему заменой оператора либо же снятием нагрузки на сеть (если у вас кто-то сидит в интернете и использует много трафика, то отсоедините его от интернета)